How to Encode a String into a Valid Python Variable Name and Decode It Back Efficiently?
I need to encode arbitrary strings into valid Python variable names and be able to decode them back to the original strings. The strings may contain any characters, including those that are not valid in Python variable names.
Here are the requirements:
Valid Python Variable Name: The encoded string must be a valid Python variable name, which means it can only contain letters, digits, and underscores, and must start with a letter or an underscore.
Reversible: The encoding should be reversible, allowing me to decode the variable name back to the original string.
Efficiency: The encoding and decoding process should be efficient enough for use in a server application.
I’ve tried using base64 encoding but ran into issues with characters like - and _. I also considered using werkzeug.security to hash the string, but it’s too slow for my needs in a server application. Here’s the solution I’ve come up with so far:
import base64
import re
def encode_variable_name(string):
    encoded_bytes = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(string.encode('utf-8'))
    encoded_name = encoded_bytes.decode('utf-8').rstrip('=')
    encoded_name = re.sub(r'[^0-9a-zA-Z]', lambda match: '_%02x' % ord(match.group(0)), encoded_name)
    if not encoded_name[0].isalpha():
        encoded_name = 'encoded_' + encoded_name
    return encoded_name
def decode_variable_name(encoded_name):
    if encoded_name.startswith('encoded_'):
        encoded_name = encoded_name[len('encoded_'):]
    encoded_name = re.sub(r'_(\w{2})', lambda match: chr(int(match.group(1), 16)), encoded_name)
    padded_name = encoded_name + '=' * (-len(encoded_name) % 4)
    decoded_bytes = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(padded_name)
    decoded_string = decoded_bytes.decode('utf-8')
    return decoded_string
original_string = '`پگ\'"=-_'
encoded_name = encode_variable_name(original_string)
decoded_string = decode_variable_name(encoded_name)

Considerations:
Werkzeug Security: I considered using werkzeug.security for hashing the string to ensure a valid variable name, but it proved to be too slow for my server application.
Questions:
Is this approach reliable for all possible input strings?
Are there any edge cases I might have missed that could cause the encoded variable name to be invalid?
Is there a more efficient method to achieve the same goal?
Any suggestions or improvements would be greatly appreciated!

Please visit the [help] to remind yourself how to ask good questions here. For starters, a question should contain ONE question, not many. Also note: this site isn't a "here are my requirements, here is my code, is that good" service. In other words: your question boils down to "can someone help with my assignment", and that isn't a legit question around here.

Why are you messing around with encoding, or variable names at all?  ANY string works just fine as-is, as a key in a dictionary.

@jasonharper I want to store the users data and I noticed that storing data in separated variables is less memory consuming and faster than dictionaries. And besides of that, There is a reason that I can't use dictionaries.

I think your base64 idea is definitely going to work!  Consider the character set use for base64:
Numbers: '0123456789'
Symbols: '+/'
Uppercase letters: 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
Lowercase letters: 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
Padding character: '='

And the rules for python variables:
P1.  A variable name must start with a letter or the underscore character
P2.  A variable name cannot start with a number
P3.  A variable name can only contain alpha-numeric characters and underscores (A-z, 0-9, and _ )
P4.  Variable names are case-sensitive (age, Age and AGE are three different variables)
P5.  A variable name cannot be any of the Python keywords.

And you basically have your answer:
You can use the under char _ to further encode the base64 results into a valid python variable.
Here's what I'm suggesting:

base64 encode the data
prepend the result with a _ (this fulfills P1, P2 and P5).
Convert any +, /, or = characters to "underscore encoded".  + --> _P and / --> _S and = --> _E.  This fulfills P3.
Regarding P5, none of the python keywords start with a _ so suggestion 2 above meets this criteria.

Of course, to get the data back, just remove the underscore prefix and then  un-underderscore encode.

I can use non-64base characters to separate them.
Thanks to everyone!
